# Typescript types for a function that takes an interface property name as input

Tags: typescript

I have a problem getting typescript to accept a simple one-liner method and cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.
[Here is the code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-issue-property-handlers-n99xit).

### Context

Given the following typescript definitions which I cannot change

```
interface Properties {
    id: number
    color: string
    […]
}

type PropertyHandlers = {
    [Property in keyof Properties]: (value: Properties[Property] | undefined) => void
}

const handlers: PropertyHandlers = {
    id: value => console.log(value ?? 123),
    color: value => console.log(value ?? 'red'),
    […]
}
```

### Goal

I need to write a method `handleProperty` that takes as input the name of a property as well as a `values: Partial<Properties>` parameter such that it fulfills these example calls:

```
handleProperty('id', {}) // should call handlers.id(undefined)
handleProperty('id', { color: 'blue' }) // should call handlers.id(undefined)
handleProperty('id', { id: 42 }) // should call handlers.id(42)
// similar for 'color' and such
```

i.e. it calls the handler for the given property name with the value given in the second parameter if it is available or `undefined` otherwise.
How can I implement this **in a way that is Typescript compatible**?

### Current Approach

```
const handleProperty = <T extends keyof Properties>(property: T, overrides: Partial<Properties>) => {
    return handlers[property](overrides[property])
}
```

This implementation has the intended functionality but the typescript compiler raises an error

```
properties.ts:16:28 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'Partial<Properties>[T]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Properties[T]'.
  Type 'Partial<Properties>' is not assignable to type 'Properties'.
    Property 'id' is optional in type 'Partial<Properties>' but required in type 'Properties'.

16  return handlers[property](overrides[property])
                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The above error message is from my local typescript v4.7.4 installation on Ubuntu with node 18 without any tsconfig.
One thing to note is that [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-issue-property-handlers-n99xit) shows a slightly different error message but still points to the same code location.

Comment: The reason for different error messages is probably the default tsconfig that varies across platforms. Did you use your own tsconfig when trying all the services?

Comment: I doubt you are using TSv4.7.4 if you're getting that error message.  [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) should have cleared that up, and that was released with TSv4.6.  Can you triple check?

Comment: @jcalz `tsc --version` outputs `Version 4.7.4` and `tsc properties.ts` prints the `TS2345` error message. I'm using a clean node:18 docker container for this post and installed typescript with `npm i -g typescript` just a few minutes ago, so I don't think there's any chance of outdated packages. I've never used `tsc` directly tho, is there any chance that I'm doing something wrong with these commands?

Comment: @hhearts I think you're probably right about the differing error messages so I shortened that part of my question as I don't think its that important to the question itself. But I did copy my local tsconfig (clean, just generated by a `tsc --init`) over to Codesandbox and still receive slightly different error messages but I can't figure out why

Comment: I just noticed that the problem occurs only when `strictNullChecks` is deactivated. As soon as I set it to `true`, the issue disappears.

Comment: Hmm, yeah I never even use TS without `--strict` enabled.  Weird things happen in the name of backward compatibility.

Comment: @jcalz I also wouldn't have disabled strict mode if it was up to me. But getting more errors with fewer strict options enabled is unexpected behavior, isn't it? You seem to be quite active in the TS Github issues, so I'll ask you here first: Should I open up an issue for this?